# KendoWindow: setOptions is not working to set actions

Tags: kendo-ui

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/kQ5Sm/18/) I have two KendoWindow objects. The first one, dialog1, has a custom icon on the bar. The second one, dialog2, doesn't have the icon even though the "actions" attribute is set with setOptions.

Any ideas why setOptions is not working?

This is the javascript:

```
$("#dialog1").kendoWindow({   
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      actions: ["Custom", "Close"]
});

$("#dialog1").closest(".k-window").css({
    top: 20,
    left: 20
});


$("#dialog2").kendoWindow();
var dialog2 = $("#dialog2").data("kendoWindow");

dialog2.setOptions({
     width: 200,
     height: 200,
     actions: ["Custom", "Close"]
});

$("#dialog2").closest(".k-window").css({
    top: 20,
    left: 300
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kendo team actually just fixed this bug Oct 14, 2014.

Here is the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/327#issue-45737505) and the [commit that fixes it](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/commit/97554da94c83be4152f547ed84b051e87f61f9d1).

You can wait for the next release, or if you are using the free/opensource Kendo UI Core, then you can make a new build from the GitHub repo. I think if you are using the paid version of Kendo UI, there might be a way to download the latest internal build from your Telerik account.